# Springboot project failed to start with tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis

**Error:**

> Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V"

**Logs:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
... 67 common frames omitted
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:234)
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:127)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.<init>(XMLConfigBuilder.java:81)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:502)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:475)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
```

**Dependicies:**

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!--MyBatis-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!--单元测试-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!--MySQL依赖-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<!--lombok：主要用于log-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
<!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!-- 添加servlet依赖模块 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- 添加jstl标签库依赖模块 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!--添加tomcat依赖模块.-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Json工具 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.47</version>
</dependency>
<!--AOP-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!--xml解析-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!--热部署-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My project structure and mybatis configuration in properties:
[image: imgur link]

Comment: You're building a war and deploying it to Tomcat?  What version of Tomcat are you running?  Have you considered building an executable jar bundled with an embedded Tomcat instance, instead of a war deployment?

Comment: This is likely caused by having an ancient XML parser (JAXP implementations) on your classpath.

Comment: The problem is solved. The problem appears in < mybatis-spring-boot-starter >. Remove the mybatis in this package, and then add the mybatis dependency to run it

Comment: @PengHusile Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Additionally, please use mybatis below 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using another XML parser or at least newer version of `dom4j`, for example version 2.1.1, since it is better compatible with Java8.

Also simplify your mybatis config (without `classpath:` or invalid `classpath*:` prefix):

```
mybatis.config-location: mybatis-config.xml
mybatis.mapper-locations: mapper/*.xml
```